# Java Font Corruption Issue in ChemAxon JChem

Tags: java, fonts, corrupt

I'm working with the ChemAxon JChem cheminformatics application to develop a web-based browsable and searchable chemical products catalog.

I'm running into a serious issue regarding displaying of fonts inside of images generated by the Java web service that powers JChem. Here is the thread on ChemAxon's official support forum for more background: https://www.chemaxon.com/forum/ftopic5909.html

Here is an example of fonts being rendered incorrectly:
https://www.chemaxon.com/forum/files/ajax-garbled-output.png

Here, you will notice that when a molecule image is selected, fonts appear to render correctly. Otherwise, they appear as garbled abstract vector art.

I do not experience any issues regarding fonts on my development server which is a Debian Etch system running Sun Java 1.5.0.14. The production server, a CentOS server running Java 1.5.0.22 is the system exhibiting corruption issues. Note that I have also tried using 1.6.X Java on the production server with no results.

It was pointed out to me by ChemAxon support personnel that the fontconfig.properties files that are used to configure Java's font support may be responsible.

Here are the fontconfig.properties files corresponding to my (displaying correctlly) development server:
https://www.chemaxon.com/forum/fonts-development-server.tar-download6823.gz

Here are the fontconfig.properties files corresponding to my (displaying incorrectly) production server:
https://www.chemaxon.com/forum/fonts-production-server.tar-download6824.gz

If you could help me get fonts displaying correctly on my production server, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by performing a clean installation of Java 1.6 packages via yum. I was unable to manually fix this issue by adjusting font configuration files.